# Is "how much is this worth?" on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-off-topic

I'm curious whether a question relating to pricing a bicycle-related component or whole bike would be on topic. I know we generally frown on the "do my shopping for me" questions, but also allow the this vs. that comparisons if given enough constraints. I'm particularly interested because I intend to ask one and not have it closed. Example would be:

> How much would you value this bike at:  2011 SomeBikeBrand AndModel
>
> - Part #1
> - Upgrade #2
> - Replacement #3
>
> Ridden moderately, wintered in warm garage, etc.

Comment: In this vs that, I think its OK if theres a more general question at hand. For example, a recent trek 7.2 vs 7.5 thread also had something on replacement parts on older bikes and compatibility in it, not just should i buy this or that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would be of the opinion that this is off topic for the following reasons:

- Actual condition of items is impossible to judge without inspection, and therefore impossible to price accurately.
- The price of a whole bike is largely dependent on the included components, and we will frequently get posts where the list or pictures of components will be incomplete.
- Bicycles and components depreciate rapidly, so a price given today is out of date next year.
- Value is sometimes highly dependent on location.

For those reasons I don't think the make a good fit for a Q&A site.

Comment: In addition, you'd get different answers, all as valid as each other, but all different. The poster is effectively no better off than before they asked the question. So I'd say off-topic because it doesn't add value.

Comment: I agree that they're not a good fit, but I'd say it would be better to close them as not constructive or primarily opinion based rather than off topic, for exactly the reasons that you list.

Comment: Value is also quite local. At the extreme, one LBS brings in containers of second hand bikes from Netherlands/EU and sells them here at a tidy profit.

Comment: There are also websites dedicated to this like bicyclebluebook.com.

Comment: Thanks guys. @Batman, I like bluebook but it's list of upgrades is pathetic so it's barely useful if you're not selling a stock bike.

Comment: To avoid helping bike thieves I would like to suggest that people asking for prices of their bike are requested to post frame numbers. Nobody who rightfully owns a bike should have a reason not to do it whereas a thief would.